# Copy pasting a continuous/contiguous range of cells from one worksheet to another with merged cells in the destination worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked for solution across the internet but couldn't find or probably understand any. I have limited excel vba knowledge, but am good with modifying and using existing codes to suit my purposes.

I am trying to copy data in a range of cells (A:H) from this sheet named 'Transactions DB' to cells (B:I) starting on row 24 in another sheet named 'Dashboard' in the same workbook.

The problem being that 'Dashboard' has a couple of unavoidable merged cells 'C:D' and 'G:H'. While pasting data here the merged cells gets unmerged and separate data is pasted in C&D and G&H treating them as 2 different cells. Need help to ensure that cells C&D and G&H remain merged when data is pasted. I hope I have posted my issue correctly for you to help.

```
Sub FTCH_DATA()
  a = Worksheets("Transactions DB").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Range("B24:J5000").ClearContents

  For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Transactions DB").Cells(i, Range("F9")).Value = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("E10") Then

      Worksheets("Transactions DB").Range("A" & i, "H" & i).Copy
      Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
      b = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
      Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(b + 1, 2).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
      Range("E10").Select

    End If

  Next

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer is you can't. The only alternative would be to assign each value to each cell individually e.g. ws2.Range("C24") = ws1.Range("B24") & vbnewline & ws1.Range("B25")

Comment: If the target merge pattern is simple you may re-merge the cells programmaticlly after paste  ?

Comment: @Absinthe - The code works perfectly fine except for taking care of the merged cell in destination. A workaround to ensure data in cell C1, C2..... from source worksheet gets pasted in E24, E25.... of destination worksheet instead of D24, D25. Source worksheet 'Transaction DB' will eventually have hundreds of rows of data with fixed 8 columns. So would your solution make life difficult in future?

Comment: @TSion.D.P - Re-merging D with C after paste will cause me to lose data pasted in D24. I want that data to be in E24 while pasting.

Comment: If you can think & compile a clear set of **any** operations that will do what you want, than you can afterwords turn it to VBA code..

Comment: @Rakesh No, quite simple really, just use a for loop: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html